# How to get the this firebase value?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This is my code. But not working. I am getting null value.

[image][Database Map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2zvj9.jpg)

I want get only latitude longtitude values..

```
mLocationRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("districsubdepot").child("Jaffna");

mLocationRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        Double lt = (dataSnapshot.child("latitude").getValue(Double.class));
        Double lo=(dataSnapshot.child("logitude").getValue(Double.class));
        Toasty.success(getApplicationContext(), "value" + lt+lo).show();
    }
}
```

Finally I want to draw polyline using these latitude longitude. How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can't get partial value, unless using multiple queries.
Firebase stores data as (and acts like) a big json file. This means that it respects json standard.

In standard json, unless using advanced standards and techniques (e.g. jsonpath) you can't retrieve the data bound to multiple keys.

Comment: why sir?  not possible?

Comment: @PilojanSiva you can only get the value relative to a single key. Remember that firebase stores data (and acts like) a big json and it does not support any standard like jsonpath

Answer (score 0):

You are missing to dig into the child node with id: `"LANrjuA.....sBJ"`

It's the node just under the node `"Jaffna."`

So essentially you should update your reference as:
`mLocationRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("districsubdepot").child("Jaffna").child("LANrjuA.....sBJ");`

Obviously hard coding that ID isn't a best practice you should dynamically set/bind/pass it, but that is about the flow you're building on - not the main story here.

Hope it helps!

Comment: i want get dynamically

Comment: i have this map class